# ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build the cartographer from this site https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compilation.html

when i ran `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=${ROS_DISTRO} -y`, this error pop up

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
cartographer_ros: No definition of [tf2_eigen] for OS version [buster]
```

How do i resolve this?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339725/error:-the-following-packages/stacks-could-not-have-their-rosdep-keys-resolved-to-system-dependencies/) by [qazqwert](https://answers.ros.org/users/50214/qazqwert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So what that means is there's no compiled version of `tf2_eigen` available on your OS, Buster (I know, obvious, but trying to start with parsing the statement).

So you need to compile that package from source on your (raspberry pi?) or contact maintainers to get a released version on that OS (which will be a longer process).

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1